# objc weird warnings with PyQT5 in OSX after importing cv2

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, pyqt5

I'm getting these objective c warnings in OSX after importing cv2(no warnings otherwise) in some simple GUI app that I'm creating using PyQt5. Here is some minimal example(warnings only, no resulting errors):

**Versions:**

- PyQt5                5.10.1
- PyQt5-sip            4.19.21
- opencv-python        4.1.2.30

**Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QDesktopWidget
import sqlite3
import cv2


class EmployeeBase(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, window_title, geometry):
        super().__init__()
        self.setGeometry(*geometry)
        self.setWindowTitle(window_title)
        win_rectangle = self.frameGeometry()
        center_point = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
        win_rectangle.moveCenter(center_point)
        self.move(win_rectangle.topLeft())
        self.setStyleSheet('QPushButton:!hover {color: red}')
        self.show()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    connection = sqlite3.connect('Employees.db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    test = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = EmployeeBase('Test', (0, 0, 500, 500))
    sys.exit(test.exec_())
```

**Result:**

```
objc[1741]: Class QCocoaPageLayoutDelegate is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee5c0) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x119519f20). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QCocoaPrintPanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee638) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework/Versions/5/QtPrintSupport (0x119519f70). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QCocoaApplicationDelegate is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee340) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b9480). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QNSApplication is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee2f0) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b94d0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QCocoaMenuLoader is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee2a0) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b9570). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QNSImageView is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee660) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b9660). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QNSStatusItem is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee6b0) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b96b0). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
objc[1741]: Class QNSOpenSavePanelDelegate is implemented in both /Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui (0x110fee480) and /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqcocoa.dylib (0x1194b9750). One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
```

Comment: PyQt5 and opencv use Qt, and the error you see is because the version of Qt used to compile PyQt5 is different from the version of Qt used by opencv. It would be nice to indicate the version of pyqt5 and opencv that you have installed as well as how you installed it

Comment: @eyllanesc I edited my post, check the versions and I installed both using pip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way both Qt and OpenCV are implemented to work on Python is through a binding mechanism, in which elements in a shared native library (programmed in C++ in these both cases) can be called from the Python interpreter. This can be achieved in multiple ways, such as the [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html) module of the standard Python library.

The problem is when two shared libraries expose the same symbols. OpenCV can use Qt as the engine to build GUIs (it can use also others, but the version that you are using is compiled to include the Qt symbols). When the interpreter loads the two shared libraries (in this case `/Users/emadboctor/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/cv2/.dylibs/QtGui` and `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/lib/QtPrintSupport.framework`), it raises a warning, since the loading mechanism detected the same symbol in different places. The warning `One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.` means that it might take one or the other, but there is no predefined order or any preference. This is an issue if you are expecting certain behavior that is only implemented in one of the two (say, the cv2 library version for Qt is is version 5.1 and the PyQt one is 5.2, and a certain `doSomething` function was changed from one version to another. The loading sequence will determine the behaviur of your program in an unpredictable way).

In general, since you are at the early stages of your development, and Qt is a fairly stable library, you should be fine. In case you are running into the aforementioned issue, you can try different things, like recompiling OpenCV to use the version of Qt that you are expecting (or doing the same for PyQt). I also would recommend that you start using virtual environments, since then you can also alleviate this problem by having different versions of your dependencies for different projects.

Comment: Very thorough explanation, thanks I'll try reinstalling both and I run through PyCharm which creates virtual environments by default(I'm not sure) anyway I edited my post and added versions if you need to check.